# JQuery deja de funcionar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tengo el siguiente código en javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $("#img-loading").show();
            $("button").prop("disabled", true);
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            var url = $(this).attr("url");
            $(location).prop("href", url)
        });
        $("img").click(function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $("#img-loading").show();
            $("button").prop("disabled", true);
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            var url = $(this).attr("url");
            $(location).prop("href", url)
        });
    });
</script>
```

Básicamente lo que haces es, cuando se hace clic en una imagen o un botón, mostrar un gif animado, limpiar una variable de timeout que posee la página y luego redirigir a la url que tiene asociada la imagen o el botón donde se hizo clic.

Funciona perfectamente, pero por alguna razón, hay veces que deja de redirigir. Es decir, se hace clic en una imagen o botón, se muestra el gif animado y se limpia el timeout pero no redirecciona a la página.

Si sirve para encontrar la solución, cuando abro las herramientas de desarrollo del chrome la redirección funciona.

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser lo que este funcionando mal?

Gracias!!

Comment: Podrías dar más código, esque ahí hasta el momento no le veo error quisás es en otro lugar. PD: me dio gracia lo de 'gif animado'

Comment: Pues yo entendí perféctamente lo de "gif animado", sólo una aportación: Quizás podrías resumir las llamadas a eventos de los dos elementos, algo como: $("button,img").each(...), lo digo porque parece código repetido.

Comment: donde llamas a la fuente jquery? es directamente desde el webservice de jquery o tenes un archivo local? lo llamas antes o despues de este script? decis que mientras esta la consola de desarrollo abierta, el script funciona completo?

Comment: Tus imágenes y/o botones se generan dinámicamente o de forma normal con el cargado de toda la página?

Comment: Jajajaja, es verdad, "gif animado"...mala mía! El código de Jquery lo descargue y esta en la misma instalación del sitio y, todo el sitio, funciona en localhost con un servidor Apache (Apache no es el problema ya que el inconveniente se repite con el servidor de desarrollo de Django). Los botones e imágenes se generan con toda la página. Las llamadas tampoco parecieran ser el problema, sucede lo mismo si a los botones les doy el evento "onclick=location.href..." y que el JQuery solo deshabilite los botones y muestre el gif.

Comment: Sebastian, el script funciona (casi) siempre bien, de hecho es muy dificil replicar el error. Lo que observe una vez fue que, cuando abri la consola de desarrollo, aparentemente provocó que finalizara la ejecución de la última línea. También descarto la posibilidad de que la petición no llegue al servidor web porque sino chrome mostraría la pantalla de error por timeout.